# Books, tutorials, videos on OOP application design using Coldfusion 9

Tags: oop, web-applications, coldfusion

I am a web application developer using Coldfusion 9.  I have incorporated the use of cfc's in my code for some time.  I would done like to incorporate more OOP principles in my design.

I am looking for books, tutorials, videos, etc that cover application design and interaction using OOP principles.

Most of the material I've found covers the object design but not they are used in application design.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reading suggestions. All are great suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt Gifford wrote a fantastic book, [Object-Oriented Programming in ColdFusion](http://objectorientedprogrammingincoldfusion.com/), which I highly recommend. I wrote [a review of it](http://www.dopefly.com/techblog/entry.cfm?entry=325) earlier this year and Sean Corfield also wrote [a good review](http://corfield.org/blog/post.cfm/review-oop-in-coldfusion) if you are hesitant about buying it. Other great books I have found inspiration from are java-based OOP books, like [Head First Java](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/), which will teach you some java, but largely, OO concepts. The Head First series is both very gentle and engaging.

Outside of those books, there are a lot of great online resources, many of them are detailed on [ObjectOrientedColdFusion.org](http://www.objectorientedcoldfusion.org/) which has a low-traffic google group for you to ask questions, plus lots of great reading material, and plenty of resource links.

Another of my favorite resources is Charlie Arehart's [UGTV](http://carehart.org/ugtv/index.cfm), which has a large database of recorded presentations. I searched for "object oriented" and found some good ones like Brian Meloche's Common Sense Object Oriented ColdFusion and Bob Silverberg's Building An Object Oriented Model, which was really good when i saw it. Browse around, you will find more.

Reading code is a fantastic way to learn. The easiest way to find code to read is [GitHub's ColdFusion language page](https://github.com/languages/ColdFusion), but you can also find code through [RIAForge](http://riaforge.org/). Some good code that I know of is [BlueRiver (look into Mura CMS)](https://github.com/blueriver), [Bob Silverburg (look into Validate This](https://github.com/bobsilverberg/) and [Louis Majano and anything ColdBox related](https://github.com/ColdBox), just to name a very small few of the thousands of great code hackers out there.

Finally, remember that you are not alone in this. Many have traveled the path before and googling will help you find what they have done. For example, John Whish posted [his OOP learning strategy](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/want-to-learn-oop--213). There are a lot of us out here learning and trying things and helping others. Get involved. I mentioned the [ColdFusion OO Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/coldfusionoo), but there is a higher traffic email list, [CF-Talk](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/), which is also very helpful. Also look for local ColdFusion user groups, sometimes they have an email list or forum and they will have monthly meetings with a variety of topics. You can always find some very bright people there. Very last, there are conferences like CF.Objective() that you can attend annually which are full of amazing content.

Good luck as you learn OOP in CF!

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Programming-ColdFusion-Matt-Gifford/dp/1847196322](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196322)

http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Models.cfm

http://www.objectorientedcoldfusion.org/

Introduction to ColdFusion Components (CFCs) @ http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/events.html

http://slidesix.com/view/CFC-201

http://www.carehart.org/ugtv/index.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Once you are past the fundamentals of Object-Oriented concepts, you need a solid handle on how  to apply those concepts to your real-world projects.

An understanding of the basic Design Patterns is of significant value. You will want to start with [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), which defines these patterns, many of which are commonly used in OO design and development. For a more real-world, personal approach to the patterns, consider [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124), which builds off the first book, and demonstrates real problems that poorly designed OO systems suffer from, and how you can begin to think about solving them.

You will also want references to actual ColdFusion-related implementations of OO systems. [Object-Oriented Programming in ColdFusion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196322) is a very good start.

Finally, you should immerse yourself in existing, well-known ColdFusion applications that employ OO techniques. [ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org/) is a framework for building CFML-based websites that implements many OO techniques, including [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and you can learn a lot from this framework and websites that have been build using it.

Answer (score 0):

[Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) is an excellent book for learning design patterns and OO design principles. The examples are written in Java. I'm a CF developer with little practical Java experience but was able to follow all of the examples no problem. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 5 of my [lynda.com title](http://www.lynda.com/ColdFusion-9-tutorials/new-features/56299-2.html) also covers how to get started with ORM.